# Iterator's next returns Some(&1). Why's that?

Tags: rust

This may be a silly question, but it tackled me.

I've started learning rust, from the allmighty [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-02-iterators.html). 
In the iterator chapter (the one linked therein) there's the following example

```
fn iterator_demonstration() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut v1_iter = v1.iter();

    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}
```

The book kinda glazed over it, but I wonder - why are the ampersands needed?

edit: just to clarify - I do understand `iter` iterates through immutable references. I just don't quite grasp referencing a numeric literal (again, rookie question.)

Comment: This section of the docs clarifies what the conventions are for functions that create iterators. It might help clarify what to expect: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/#the-three-forms-of-iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they're pointers.  Follow the docs.

- `v1` is a [`Vec<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).  So `T` is `i32`.
- `Vec` doesn't have an `iter` method.  It *does* `Deref` to `[T]`.  Scroll down further.
- `[T]` has an [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) method.  It returns a `std::slice::Iter<T>`.
- `v1_iter` is an [`Iter<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), so `T` is `i32`.
- `next` is part of the `Iterator` trait, so scroll down and look for the [`impl Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator) section.
- Just below, it specifies that `next` returns an `Option<&'a T>`.  Substitute `T`, and that gives you `Option<&'a i32>`.

> Pre-emptive: *Why are they pointers?*

Because that's what you asked for.  If you wanted to *move* the contents of the `Vec` out via an iterator, you need to use `Vec::into_iter` or `Vec::drain`.

Comment: Your comment makes sense. But I feel as if my question was... slightly misunderstood. 
While I do understand why `iter` yields references, I just can't wrap my head around the `&1` (as someone who comes from a pythonic/c++-ic background, it kinda buffles me)

Comment: @avshyz That was what the first sentence of my answer was for.  It's `&1` because it's an iterator of pointers.  `1` isn't a pointer.  `&1` is a pointer to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Vec::iter()` is of type `(self :&Vec<T>) -> Q<&T>`.  That is, it creates an iterator of some type `Q` that isn't important here, that iterates over references to the `T` elements in your `Vec`.  It uses an immutable reference to the `Vec`, so it doesn't take any elements out or have any effect on the `Vec` at all.

All `Iterator`s have a `cloned()` method that turns an iterator over `&T` references into an iterator over `T` values, so long as `T` has the `Clone` trait.  It wraps the other iterator in a little bit of code that calls the `clone()` method on all the references to the elements, turning them into new `T`s.

```
fn iterator_demonstration() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut v1_iter = v1.iter().cloned();

    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}
```

`Vec` also implements `IntoIterator`, which consumes the `Vec` into an iterator over `T`, takes all the `T` in the `Vec` and passes them back.  It destroys the `Vec` and takes ownership of all its `T` values.  You can use the `into_iter()` method to explicitly use it, and it's also used in for loops.

```
fn iterator_demonstration2() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut v1_iter = v1.into_iter();

    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}


fn iterator_demonstration3() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    for i in v1 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```